# how to adjust monitor brigthness and contrast using linux?

Tags: linux, gnome, dvi, gnome3

using latest gnome and a monitor with DVI connector, i can't adjust the brigthess and contrast.

my monitor says it is getting a digital signal, and so those settings must be controlled by the source.

gnome setting for brightness that works on my laptop does nothing on the desktop.

i'm open to all kinds of suggestions. command line, conf files...

Answer (score 0):

this should help you on your way, basically, your screen is dumb and now only allows for control via DDC (Display Data Channel)  This is barely used on desktop monitors but widely used for laptops.  I did a quick Googleing and found this tool for the command line which might get you somewhere. http://jaffar.cs.msu.su/oleg/ddcci/.  Personally I use Dimmer on Windows.